# symlink or an alternative solution on GCS

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am currently using Google cloud storage to store some files. From the PHP side, I am able to use these files just fine. Now I want to extend this functionality to store 4 good versions of these files so that I can change the file path through symlink(or any other alternative way is that's not an option) on PHP side in case the latest set of files get corrupted. I am wondering how to go about this.

I appreciate any suggestions that you might have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Storage offers a [versioning system](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) as a feature that you need to enable. Versioning allows for you to save a file with the same title and the system archives the previous version and displays the new one. In this case, if there was a corruption, you would have to go into the Cloud Shell and retrieve the previous copy.

If you do not wish to go that route, I can suggest save 4 copies with distinct names(ie: fileName[number]). This way, you would take the newest file, retrieve a substring containing the number, and creating your new file based off the substring.

In both methods, you are able to roll-back to a previous version.

Cloud Storage does not allow for symlinks.

Comment: Thanks @maniSidhu98 for that information. It sounds like the versioning system works best for my use case. Does this feature allow us to control how many versions the GCS could store?

Comment: Yes. You can control the number of archived versions that are stored in GCS. This is known as [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle). With Object Lifecycle Management, you can define the [number of recent versions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#configexamples) you wish to keep, along with many other options. You can then choose what you wish to do with the older versions. This can include deleting the object or moving it to a different storage class. Keep in mind that if you delete an object, it cannot be retrieved.